# Mac Pro 10.7 - aftermarket dvd drive hangs on restart

Tags: macos, mac, mac-pro, optical-drive, restart

Drive works fine, but on restart or after a required restart from app installation - the OS looks for CD in drive. Mac will not get to the login screen. It hangs and i can see a green light on dvd drive flashes every couple of seconds. If i shutdown, then start up - no issues. Drive is LG GH22LP21 - Mac Pro 10.7.5 2x2.66 Xenon

Comment: It is time to reset your SDC !

Answer (score 1):

Master / Slave?

This is in the top bay?  And nothing is in the bottom?  There is probably a jumper to choose Master or Slave for the drive.  If it is the only one, it should be Master.